# Any way to store struct in NSCache

Tags: ios, swift, object, struct

Is there any way to store struct values in NSCache ? When I read the apple documentation look like you can only store AnyObject to it. There are couple of work around one is convert sturct to class, second convert sturct values to the dictionary but they are very expensive operation if dataset is big. Any suggestion?

Comment: What structs? Custom or any built-in? NSValue has support for some bull-in struct types.

Comment: Would it be acceptable to you to remove the objective-c tag? An Objective-C struct is a C struct — no behaviour, only data — which is easily wrapped in an `NSValue`, which has no bearing upon what you're actually asking. So that might avoid some unhelpful answers.

Comment: Removed Objective C tag

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm going to chance my arm on a 'no' (without workarounds). `NSCache` is resoundingly over on the Objective-C side of the runtime, written to work with `NSObject`s, bridged via `AnyObject`. Unlike `NSDictionary` and `NSArray` there is no equivalent Swift collection that the compiler can bridge between.

Implementation points aside: `NSCache` simply doesn't live in a world that understands value semantics for anything more sophisticated than C atoms.

That being said, probably the easiest workaround is just to create an object container for your struct, making the bridging explicit but owned by whomever wants to use the cache:

```
class YourStructHolder: NSObject {
    let thing: YourStruct
    init(thing: YourStruct) {
        self.thing = thing
    }
}

cache.setObject(YourStructHolder(thing: thing), forKey:"Whatever")
(cache.objectForKey("Whatever") as? YourStructHolder)?.thing
```

... or skip the `init` and use a `var ...: YourStruct?` if you're happy with mutability. You're going to have to deal with optionality when talking to the cache anyway.

Comment: Thankyou for the answer. But you can make this very generic as well, instate of using "YourStruct" just use "Any" and when you decode back just do downcasting.

Comment: This is less than ideal, because this isn't flexible enough to be used in a general-purpose way, and using Any would prevent the type system from knowing anything about the underlying struct. Check my answer below.

Comment: For the record, I agree with @WilliamTFroggard — using a template in this case exactly captures the generic part of the task without forfeiting type safety. He has my vote.

Answer (score 11):

The best option in this case is to use a template. That way, you can maintain type safety, and you don't have to force downcast.

```
class StructWrapper<T>: NSObject {

    let value: T

    init(_ _struct: T) {
        self.value = _struct
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think converting struct to NSValue is very expensive (both are almost pure data) but you have to make some measuring:

```
struct myStruct {
    int x;
    int y;
};
typedef struct myStruct myStruct;
```

To wrap:

```
NSValue *object = [NSValue value:&myStruct withObjCType:@encode(myStruct)];
```

To unwrap:

```
myStruct struct;
[object getValue:&struct];
```

Comment: I need to do this in swift

Comment: @AAV You have a nice example to work on, try implementing the same methods in Swift and then ask another question if you are still having trouble.

Comment: @Abizern, I have already tried this. You can't use withObjCType in swift.